# Update of the not immediate state in Example Counter - BloC Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

My pubspec.yml:

```
  bloc: ^4.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^4.0.0
  equatable: ^1.2.5
```

I created my CounterBloc:

```
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  @override
  int get initialState => 0;

  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(event) async* {
    if (event.status == EventStatus.INCREMENT) {
      yield state + event.value;
    } else if (event.status == EventStatus.DECREMENT) {
      yield state - event.value;
    }
  }
}
```

```
enum EventStatus { INCREMENT, DECREMENT }

class CounterEvent {
  final int value;
  final EventStatus status;

  const CounterEvent({this.value, this.status});
}
```

```
void main() => runApp(CounterApp());

class CounterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BLoC Demo',
      home: BlocProvider<CounterBloc>(
        create: (context) => CounterBloc(),
        lazy: false,
        child: TestBlocWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class TestBlocWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterBloc = BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, int>(
          builder: (ctx, state) {
            return Text(
              'count: $state',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print("test 0 = " + counterBloc.state.toString());
                counterBloc.add(CounterEvent(value: 1, status: EventStatus.INCREMENT));
                print("test 1 = " + counterBloc.state.toString());
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("test 2 = " + counterBloc.state.toString());
                counterBloc
                    .add(CounterEvent(value: 1, status: EventStatus.DECREMENT));
                print("test 3 = " + counterBloc.state.toString());
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then my question is:

Inside FloatingActionButton, I increment value to my state;
But I print before increment and after increment and the state is the same value;
test 0 = 0;
test 1 = 0;
Why?
In the screen reflect my value, but not immediately in my prints inside FloatingActionButton;

After I tested this:

````
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print("test 0 = " + counterBloc.state.toString());
                counterBloc
                    .add(CounterEvent(value: 1, status: EventStatus.INCREMENT));
                await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 0));
                print("test 1 = " + counterBloc.state.toString());
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            ),
    ```

Note: I put "await Future.delayed", after my CounterBloc, with value 0 in my FloatingActionButton;
Works;
test 0 = 0;
test 1 = 1;
````

Answer (score 0):

That is because of how the scheduler works. Dart code is executed on a single event loop. The order in which instructions are executed is influenced by `await`.

Without the `Future.delayed` (you could have used `Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` by the way) when code in the `onPressed` lambda is executed entirely sequentially. The [`add`](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/Bloc/add.html) method calls `mapEventToState` which is an async method (generator really). When Dart encounters such a method it will schedule it for later execution and progress to the next instruction. Therefor you will see `0` twice.

This changes when you add an `await` call like your `Future.delayed`. Dart will then stop and see what else it can run. In this case the `mapEventToState`. It will run that one and after it will continue on with the remainder of the `onPressed` lambda. That is why you see `1` with the awaited `Future.delayed`.